# In a Liferay hook, for a custom Upgrade Process, what is the way to roll back the release number for a custom upgrade?

Tags: liferay, hook

I've created an upgrade process that extends **com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess**. In it I run some queries to modify the our database tables.

The issue is with the **release number**. On my local I've had to gradually increment it as I play around with the java SQL syntax to make sure the process will execute successfully. Now I have something like release **321** in the liferay database table **RELEASE_** but I want to modify the SQL without creating another upgrade process.

I've tried modifying this table and changing **BUILDNUMBER** but when I redeploy the hook Liferay still gives me the same message about trying to upgrade with an old version.

So the question: is there a way to **reset** the **release** in the database for this hook back down so I can re-run it with updated SQL or just fix my build number to match what is on our other environments?

Comment: I think that is what the purpose of the build.number is, you can update that in your plugin and deploy the plugin to again run the Upgrade process. If there is a change then in UpgradeProcess it should ideally be a increment to the build number. Not sure why you would want to reset it though, only for development purpose?

Comment: Thanks Prakash, there is a different property called 'build.number' different from 'release.info.build.number'? Yes, its for development. Right now I am throwing an Exception at the end of the doUpgrade to prevent the build from incrementing.

Comment: If you want to always run the upgradeProcess than you can simply return `0` in the `getThreshold()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out modifying the **RELEASE_** table does work. However the changes do not take affect until the application server is **restarted**.